# Search multiple tables php activerecord

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I have two tables in mysql

Users:
-id
-name
-email
-role

Position
-id
-position

I need to build a search term using PHPActiveRecord in Codeigniter. 
A user types a term say 'John' or 'Designer' and i need to search it in the users as well as the postions table.
I can search for the term in the Users table using like operator but can't figure out how to search in position field also in the Positions table.

The code i have use to search in a single table is as follows:

```
/**
 * 
 * Search users based on parameters
 * @param integer $limit
 * @param integer $start
 * @param string $term
 */
public function search_candidates($limit, $start, $term, $role)
{
  $candidates = User::all(array(
                                'conditions' => "('role' => $role) 
                                  AND ((name like '%".$term."%') 
                                  OR (email like '%".$term."%'))",
                                'limit' => $limit,
                                'offset' => $start,
                                'order' => "name"
  ));

  return $candidates;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to perform this search.
http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders#joins, which explains htat you can add joins to your query

```
  $candidates = User::all(array(
                            'joins'=>'LEFT JOIN position on (normal left join stuff)
                            'conditions' => "('role' => $role) 
                              AND ((name like '%".$term."%') 
                              OR (email like '%".$term."%'))",
                              //(Your extra where conditions for the position)
                            'limit' => $limit,
                            'offset' => $start,
                            'order' => "name"
));
```

I think that should at least get you on the right track.

Also, you're leaving your query open to SQL injection when you use custom conditions in that way.
You HAVE to use query placeholders, otherwise you're just putting raw input into the queries.

`User::find($id)` is automatically escaped.

`User::all(array('conditions'=>'id'=>1))` is automatically escaped

`User::all(array('conditions'=>"id = $id"))` is NOT escaped.

You have to do `User::find(array('conditions'=>'id = ?', array($id)));`

Your query would be transformed to look something like this.

```
 $candidates = User::all(array(
                            'conditions' => "('role' = ?) 
                              AND ((name like ?) 
                              OR (email like ?))",
                            'limit' => $limit,
                            'offset' => $start,
                            'order' => "name"
  ),array($role,"%$term%","%$term%");
```